# Can boost boost::posix_time::milliseconds turn value near to 0 into 0?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, time, sleep

So I created some code. I use boost timers. here it is

```
      while(1){
        timerForCaptureFame.restart();
   //some code
        spendedTimeForCaptureFame = timerForCaptureFame.elapsed();
        if(spendedTimeForCaptureFame < desiredTimeForCaptureFame){
                boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(desiredTimeForCaptureFame - spendedTimeForCaptureFame));
        }
}
```

can it happen so that `desiredTimeForCaptureFame - spendedTimeForCaptureFame` would be > 0 but boost will take it as 0 and just pause the thread?

Comment: nope - desired time is set before this thread starts.

Comment: I mean the problem is - thread works for some time than falls to sleep...

Comment: deleted my original comment now that it looks like you're using boost::timer so you're dealing with doubles.

Comment: You're converting from `double` to `long` so yes, you will have rounding errors. Also boost::timer it's not very accurate (it measures seconds) so you're even more likely to get 0 when converting to `long`. You can do something like `long elapsedTime = 1000 * static_cast< long >( desiredTimeForCaptureFame - spendedTimeForCaptureFame ); if( elapsedTime > 0 ){ sleep(...); }`. What I'm not so sure about is if `this_thread::sleep( 0 );` sleeps forever...

Answer (score 2):

`boost::this_thread::sleep(0)` should not "pause the thread"; it should just return immediately. There have been bug reports posted about `boost::this_thread::sleep` hanging, so it may be that you have hit this bug --- if so, I would be grateful of more details as I have been unable to reproduce it myself.